# Django Verbose Name being lost

Tags: django, django-forms

I was wondering if someone could explain to me why my verbose_name attribute of a model fields is being lost when using the follow code;

`Model`:

```
information_request_issued_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date Information Request Issued', null=True, blank=True)
```

`Form` class:

```
class InformationRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = DevelopmentAssessment
    fields = ('information_request_issued_date')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(InformationRequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['information_request_issued_date'] = forms.DateField(('%d/%m/%Y',), widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'class': 'date'}))
```

If i don't have the `self.fields` declaration in the form class the `verbose_name` works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because it's now a regular form field and thus doesn't have an attribute named `verbose_name`. Instead, it now has a `label` attribute.

Try this:

```
self.fields['information_request_issued_date'].label = 'Date Information Request Issued'
```

Comment: damn I thought that might be the case, shame thought I could manage it in the model.. Cheers!